# DRF Many-to-Many reversed serializer

Tags: api, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, reverse

I want to make some api with `person_id`.
But I can't handle my ModelSerializers with this models.

How may I define my serializer?

**models.py**

```
class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True,
    vaccinations = models.ManyToManyField(Vaccine,
                                          through='Vaccination',
                                          through_fields=('person', 'vaccine'))


class Vaccination(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vaccine = models.ForeignKey(Vaccine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reserved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    is_edited = models.BooleanField()
```

**want to:**
GET `http://localhost:8000/person/123/vaccinations`

```
{
    'person_id': 123,
    'vaccines': [
        {
            'name': 'Flu',
            'description': 'Flu',
            'vaccinations': [
                {
                    'reserved_at': '2020-12-25',
                    'is_edited': true
                },
                {
                    'reserved_at': '2020-12-31',
                    'is_edited': false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your read.

Answer (score 0):

I have write the code for you. Try this one:

**serializers:**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import *


class VaccinationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vaccination
        fields = "__all__"

class VaccineSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    vaccinations = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_vaccinations(self,instance):
        qs = Vaccination.objects.filter(vaccine =instance.id)
        data = VaccinationSerializer(qs,many=True).data
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Vaccine
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views:**

```
class VaccineDetailAPIView(APIView):
    # permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        _id = self.kwargs['pk']
       
        try:
            obj=Vaccine.objects.get(id=_id)
        except:
            return Response({'success' : 'False','message':'No object found'},status=400)

        queryset = Vaccine.objects.filter(id=_id)
        serializer = VaccineSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request':request})
        data = serializer.data

        if data:
            return Response({
                'success' : 'True',
                'message' : 'Data retrieved successfully',
                'data'    : data,
            },status=200)

        else:
            return Response({
                'message':'No data to retrieve',
                'success':'False'
            },status=400)
```

**urls:**

```
path('person/<int:pk>/vaccinations', VaccineDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='vaccine_detail'),
```